# Feed output from dpdk-created TAP into QEMU Virtual Network Interface

Tags: networking, qemu, tap, virtio

I have this DPDK command line:

```
sudo dpdk-testpmd -l 0-3 -n 4 \
    --vdev 'net_pcap0,rx_pcap=/path/to/input.pcap' \
    --vdev 'net_tap0,mac=fixed' -- -i --no-flush-rx
```

This works within the host, as this shows:

```
$ tcpdump -D
...
5.dtap0 [Up, Running, Connected]
...
$ tcpdump -i 5
# Other terminal
testpmd> start
```

The expected data gets dumped from the file to `dtap0`.

With QEMU, I add a new NIC to an instance of Ubuntu 20.04 with the following settings:

[image]

Note the IP address is unknown, which I think is the cause of my problem. How do I get an IP assigned?

In the VM I get this:

```
$ tcpdump -D
...
7.enp7s0 [none]
```

**Update:**

I forgot to mention this in the VM, but it still doesn't work.:

```
$ sudo ifconfig enp7s0 up
$ tcpdump -D
...
2.enp7s0 [Up, Running]
```

I have also noticed that I have an IPv6 address in the VM, but no IPv4 address. The TAP port in the host VM also only has an IPv6 address.